# Nesting layouts in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to nest layouts in Rails 3.2? I'd like to create a generic layout used by application.html.erb and allow a couple views in the application to use it. I found the [Nested Layouts](https://github.com/eric/nested-layouts) ruby gem, but it hasn't been updated in four years. It would be awesome if I could do something like the following in my application.html.erb file:

```
<% inside_layout 'html5_boilerplate' do %>
  <div id="container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found an easy solution in [this blog post](http://m.onkey.org/nested-layouts-in-rails-3).

In my `ApplicationHelper`, I added the following:

```
def parent_layout(layout)
  @view_flow.set(:layout, output_buffer)
  self.output_buffer = render(:file => "layouts/#{layout}")
end
```

In application.html.erb, I added:

```
<% parent_layout 'html5_boilerplate' %>
```

Comment: For anyone coming across this, I'm using [Nestive](https://github.com/rwz/nestive) now and it works well.

Answer (score 5):

I tried a few of these, but none worked for me in Rails 4.  But with a little inspiration from the [nested_layouts](https://github.com/sunteya/nested_layouts/blob/master/lib/nested_layouts.rb) gem, I came up with the following simple fix:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def inside_layout(layout, &block)
    layout = "layouts/#{layout}" unless layout =~ %r[\Alayouts/]
    content_for :content, capture(&block)
    render template: layout
  end
end
```

Then I revised my `layouts/application.html.erb` template to be similar to this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <%= content_for?(:content) ? yield(:content) : yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I can declare a nested layout like this:

```
# app/views/layouts/blog.html.erb
<%= inside_layout 'application' do %>
  <div id="blog_container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `content_for` method [as described in the official Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-the-content-for-method).

Comment: Can you use that for a layout nested within a layout?

Comment: Yes, see also http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for or http://railscasts.com/episodes/8-layouts-and-content-for

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still not following this approach. How can I use content_for to render a layout within a layout? Could you provide a code example?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Your application layout is going to surround everything in your app. so really just build those partials into the relationships you have on the individual view level.

I have a person object that has some other parts of the model included in their partial render in a div like below. It's not pretty but it hopefully is along the lines of what you want to accomplish.

```
<div id="div-1">
    <fieldset><legend><b>Registrant Information</b></legend>
        <fieldset><legend><b>Personal Information</b></legend>
          <p class="field">
            <%= f.label "First Name" %>
            <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <%= f.label "Last Name" %>
            <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <%= f.label "Middle Init" %>
            <%= f.text_field :middleinit, :size=>2 %>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <%= f.label "Nickname" %>
            <%= f.text_field :nickname %>
            </p> 
          <p class="field"> 
            <%= f.label :birthdate %>
            <%= f.date_select :birthdate, :start_year=>1935%>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <%= f.label :gender %>
            <%= f.select :gender, ['Male','Female'] %>
            </p> 
          <p class="field">
            <%= f.label "T-Shirt Size" %><br />
            <%= f.select :shirtsize, ['YS','YM','YL','S','M','L','XL','XXL'] %>
            </p>
        </fieldset><br/>
        <fieldset><legend><b>Address Information</b></legend>
          <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |builder| %>
            <%= render "address_fields", f: builder %>
          <% end %>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset><legend><b>Email</b></legend>
            <%= f.fields_for :emails do |builder| %>
                <%= render "email_fields", f: builder %>
            <% end %>
            <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Email", f, :emails %>
        </fieldset>
    </fieldset>    
</div>
```

Comment: For my use case, I'm trying to create two layouts, an application.html.erb layout that contains the basic markup for my application and an HTML5 Boilerplate layout. I have a few pages in my application that won't use use my main application layout (such as my landing page) and I'd like them to use the HTML5 Boilerplate layout. The problem with this approach is I don't want to render something inside my view (which would be a greate place to use partials), I was to render my view inside of application.html.erb, which would be rendered inside of html5_boilerplate.html.erb.