# Ruby Layout Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I was wondering if there is any layout inheritance implementation in ruby.
In symfony, you can do this:

```
layoutmain.html
Give <head> and all that here
<body>
<h3>{{title}}</h3>

{{block view}}
<div class="row">
<div class="span3">
{{content}}
</div>
</div>

{{end block}}


</body>


layout2.html
{{inherits layoutman}}
{{block view}}
 <div class="container">
Structure it differently
 </div>
{{end block}}
```

So to speak, it let's you inherit the whole template and override parts for a different layout. So the scripts etc stay as they are in the main template, but you can change the view structure. So you can reuse bits of code in the first layout

I found some liquid inheritance project on github, but it looked outdated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the following approach to achieve "nesting" of layouts which is the form of layout inheritance that I've found to be most useful.

In the main application helper module `app/helpers/application_helper.rb` I define a helper method `parent_layout`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def parent_layout(layout)
    @view_flow.set(:layout, self.output_buffer)
    self.output_buffer = render(:file => layout)
  end
end
```

This helper is responsible for capturing the output of the current layout and then rendering the specified parent layout with the child layout inserted when the parent `yield`s.

Then in my views I can set up the layout inheritance as follows. I start with my main application layout `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` which is the *child* layout in this configuration:

```
<div class="content">
  <h1><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : 'Untitled' %></h1>
  <div class="inner">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</div>
<%= parent_layout 'layouts/container' %>
```

The call to the helper method `parent_layout` specifies that `application.html.erb` is a child layout of `container.html.erb`. I then define the *parent* layout `app/views/layouts/container.html.erb` as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

The `yield` in `container.html.erb` yields to the "derived" (or child) layout `application.html.erb`, i.e. it inserts the output of rendering `application.html.erb` into the `<body>` of `container.html.erb`. Note that the `parent_layout` call needs to come *at the end* of the template since it captures the output of the layout up until the point at which it is invoked.

This is based on [this](http://m.onkey.org/nested-layouts-in-rails-3) article but updated to work in Rails 3.2 (and, hopefully, later). I haven't tried it in Rails 4, but you'll be able to get something similar working.

Comment: so the container is the parent and application is the child?

Comment: That's correct. I made a couple of small edits to clarify this.

Comment: wow this is neat man. You should totally package this as a gem

Comment: I might give that some thought!

Comment: I kind of tried using this in rails4 and doesnt seem to work. Nothing happens at all. just the bare application.html.erb file is rendered. without any of the good stuff from container. Wierdly, messing up the code inside application helper or the name of layout doesnt throw an error either

Comment: There are some solutions that work for Rails 4 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783490/nesting-layouts-in-rails. There's also the nested layouts gem: https://github.com/sunteya/nested_layouts/blob/master/lib/nested_layouts.rb.

Comment: thanks. but something else seems to be off. Its not reading the application.html.erb file at all. I added some banana code, no errors

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails views have a feature called "partials".  I partial is a view that generates a bit of html and can be included in other views. The partials can also accept arguments (local variables) that customize their behavior.  The partials can include other partials.

This is probably a good place to start learning about that: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

I have never needed to do some kind of layout inheritance thing like you are describing but I could imagine doing it pretty easily with partials and passing around ruby variables that say which partial to use in which situation.

Comment: yes ofcourse i figure i can implement a simple inheritance system with partials. Although I was looking for some sort of readymade system